# Formatting decimal values in C# based on custom format

Tags: c#

I'm facing an issue in my project while formating decimal values based on custom format.
The format set is

```
>>>,>>>,>>>,>>>,>>9.99
```

which is taken from DB.

And in C# code we were initially replacing '>' with '#' and '9' with '0'.
It works fine for values like 25.65 etc but for values like 5.00 it was showing 05.00.
So what we did was replaced '>' with '#' and '9' with '#' which solved our issue.
But this lead to a new issue again. It works fine for values like 25.65,5.00.
But for values 0.00 it shows .00.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Here the "conversion" of `>>>,>>>,>>>,>>>,>>9.99` works correctly ("5.00"). Are you using another format?

Answer (score 0):

Replace '>' with '#'

- and 9 with # before the .
- and 9 with 0 after the .

Comment: or replace the whole thing with "F2"

Comment: Replacing 9 with # before . and with 0 after . this what i'm doing now.But when the value is 0.00 it shows .00